# Nullpointer Exception in android help me out

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Null Pointer exception code:

```
ArrayList<Item> m_parts = new ArrayList<Item>();
       SQLiteDatabase db ;
      try{
         db = this.getReadableDatabase();

         Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from expenses", null );

       res.moveToFirst();
       String amt,typ,rs,dt,tp,p2,p1,p3;
       int amount;
       while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
          rs=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EXPENSES_COLUMN_AMOUNT));
          tp=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EXPENSES_COLUMN_TYPE));
          dt=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EXPENSES_COLUMN_DATE));

          amount=Integer.parseInt(rs);
            m_parts.add(new Item("hello","there", 10));
       }
      }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("new Error :"+e);
       }
       return m_parts;
```

log file

08-11 13:45:43.041: D/gralloc_goldfish(2448): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-11 13:45:46.242: D/AndroidRuntime(2448): Shutting down VM
08-11 13:45:46.313: W/dalvikvm(2448): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myexpenses/com.example.myexpenses.ListViewMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:235)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at com.example.myexpenses.Dbhelper.gettoday1(Dbhelper.java:253)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at com.example.myexpenses.ListViewMainActivity.(ListViewMainActivity.java:18)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
08-11 13:45:46.412: E/AndroidRuntime(2448):     ... 11 more

Comment: At which line do you get the NPE?

Comment: Add logCat please....

Comment: A question where we ask "Where's the text?" in place of "Where's the code?".

Comment: Show the table creation code, please.

Comment: db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: then it seems you dont have a database. But there is code missing, and logcat missing

Comment: Remove the try-catch or at least log the full exception stacktrace to learn what's wrong. In case it's NPE in `getReadableDatabase()` and it's the regular `SQLiteOpenHelper`, make sure you're passing a valid `Context` to its constructor.

Comment: i using Dababase its all working fine with other function only this on this function i am getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Context` you pass to your `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor is not a valid `Context` and its base context is `null`.

That's likely due to passing an `Activity` you instantiated yourself with `new` as a `Context`. Never instantiate activities with `new`.